# Enabling WCF Reading of an already existing MSMQ Queue

Tags: wcf, c#-4.0, msmq

I have developed a WCF Self hosted service using .Net Framework 4.0.

```
[ServiceContract(SessionMode=SessionMode.Required)]
[ServiceKnownType(typeof(XmlDocument))]
public interface IMyMSMQ
{
    [OperationContract(IsOneWay=true, Action="*")]
    void OnMessageReceived(MsmqMessage<XmlDocument> msg);
}
```

My Class implementation of this interface looks like this.

```
public class MyMSMQ : IMyMSMQ, IErrorHandler 
{
    public void OnMessageReceived(MsmqMessage<XmlDocument> msg)
    {
      // Log Message To appropriate destination
      Logger.LogMessage(msg);
    }
}
```

I have tried multiple scenarios.

Scenario 1:

1. Launch service.
2. Launch Client app.
3. Send Message to queue using Client App
4. Notice that the Queue does not appear to get populated with the message because the service already read the message.
5. Notice that nothing else happens in the service.
6. Send one more message
7. Notice that message stays in the queue

Scenario # 2:  This is similar to Scenario 1 but starting the apps were in different order

1. Launch Client app.
2. Send Message to queue using Client App
3. Notice that the Queue does appear to get populated with the message because the service is not started and has not read the message.
4. Launch service.
5. Notice that the message disappears.
6. Notice that nothing else happens in the service.
7. Send one more message
8. Notice that message stays in the queue

Every time the service starts, a message is removed from the queue so, it appears that my service IS in fact reading the message but it is not able to figure out where to send it or what to do with it once it reads the message.

Comment: It looks like you're using the `msmqIntegrationBinding` for your app. Here is a [link to a working sample](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751435(v=VS.85).aspx) using that binding. Get the sample working and compare it to your code to see what might not be wired up correctly.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I have looked at the sample, and the key difference between that example and my code is that I am adding my endpoints in code, and not in config.

I have added an event handler to the CommunicationObject.Faulted event.  When it reads the first message off the queue, this event is triggered, but it is not very informative.

Comment: I found the problem.  It was Programmer Error.

I have a custom ServiceHost class that I use to build up my endpoints.

I was using this MSMQ Endpoint
    NetMsmqBinding binding = new NetMsmqBinding();
    binding.Security = NetMsmqSecurityMode.None;


When I changed it to this:

    MsmqIntegrationBinding binding = new MsmqIntegrationBinding(MsmqIntegrationSecurityMode.None);

My code started working and no faults occurred.

Comment: Great! It can be easy to confuse the two...

Answer (score 1):

I found out that the code in the WCF Library was not the problem.  It was how I was defining the endpoint binding.

```
            MsmqIntegrationBinding binding = new MsmqIntegrationBinding(MsmqIntegrationSecurityMode.None);
            binding.ReceiveTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 1, 0);  // set timeout to 1 minute.
            binding.ReceiveErrorHandling = ReceiveErrorHandling.Fault;

            this.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(eRxMsmqWCF.IeRxMSMQ), binding, GetMQUri());
```

It needed to have the `MsmqIntegrationBinding` (which requires you to include the following using statement:  `using System.ServiceModel.MsmqIntegration;`.

Sometimes I rely on intellisense too much.  The `MsmqIntegrationBinding` is not present under the standard `System.ServiceModel` where the other bindings are located.  So I used the `NetMsmqBinding` instead.